# Windows DNS Server 2016 Forwarders unable to resolve FQDN

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2016

**Hi,
About a week back, our DNS server starting having a strange issue, where is it is not able to Resolve the Its own FQDN name.
Event viewer is giving us event ID: 4015**

Few things I tried:
restart DNS service, clear DNS cache, move the order of DNS Forwarder

DNS diagnostics result:

Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
Trying to find home server...
Home Server = xxxxxxx-DC1

- Identified AD Forest.
  Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\xxxxxx-DC1
Starting test: Connectivity
The host 30a5b042-5ef3-4a11-a499-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.local could not be resolved to an
IP address. Check the DNS server, DHCP, server name, etc.
Got error while checking LDAP and RPC connectivity. Please check your firewall settings.
......................... xxxxxxxx-DC1 failed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\xxxxxxx-DC1

```
  Starting test: DNS

     DNS Tests are running and not hung. Please wait a few minutes...
     ......................... xxxxxxx-DC1 failed test DNS
```

Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones

Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones

Running partition tests on : Schema

Running partition tests on : Configuration

Running partition tests on : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Running enterprise tests on : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.local
Starting test: DNS
Test results for domain controllers:

```
        DC: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.local
        Domain: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.local


           TEST: Basic (Basc)
              Error: No LDAP connectivity
              Error: can't read network adapter information through WMI
              Warning: The A record for this DC was not found
              Warning: The AAAA record for this DC was not found
              No host records (A or AAAA) were found for this DC
              Warning: no DNS RPC connectivity (error or non Microsoft DNS server is running)

     Summary of DNS test results:

                                        Auth Basc Forw Del  Dyn  RReg Ext
        _________________________________________________________________
        Domain: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs.local
           xxxxxx-DC1                    PASS FAIL n/a  n/a  n/a  n/a  n/a

     ......................... xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.local failed test DNS
```

Comment: What does the network configuration look like?

Comment: It looks to me like you have the server configured to use something other than your AD DNS servers. In the TCP/IPv4 properties of the network card on the server what do you have configured for DNS servers?

Comment: Perferred DNS Server: same IP as the DNS server.
Alternate DNS Server: my failed over DNS server.

For some reason, DNS settings keep getting wiped even after set it manually